# Access custom attribute and value in c# code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, code-behind

I want to access custom attribute in the code behind, how can I?

e.g. my server control

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="id_1" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl="xyz" Style="color:red"></HyperLink>
```

'Style' is not an Attribute of HyperLink as a result it is not rendered in the HTML, so I want to access the Style value in c# code behind and once I access it i can dom something like below which works.

```
id_1.Attributes.Add("Style","color:red");
```

Any help is appreciated. If you guys have any other suggestion, that is appreciated as well.

Comment: I don't think HyperLink does not have Style as Attribute? Are you talking about any specific scenario ?

Answer (score 2):

string value = id_1.Attributes["Style"].ToString();